# select one value if result of both criterias is equal

Tags: sql, select

Select value from CODE row if results of both criterias are equal.
Example of a condition:

> DAYS = 30, RATE 2 
>   AND 
>   DAYS = 60, RATE 0

Table

```
 ID | CODE| DAYS| RATE|
  1 | 01  | 30  | 2   |
  2 | 05  | 20  | 3   |
  3 | 01  | 60  | 0   |
  4 | 06  | 30  | 3   | 
 ...
```

First part is

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename WHERE (DAYS = 30 AND RATE = 2)
```

But the second part..encapsulated?

Result should be `01`

Any suggestions? thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.code
FROM Tablename t1
INNER JOIN Tablename t2 
ON t1.code = t2.code
WHERE t1.days = 30 AND t1.rate = 2
AND t2.days = 60 AND t2.rate = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CODE FROM Tablename 
WHERE (DAYS = 30 AND RATE = 2)
OR (DAYS = 60 AND RATE = 0)
```

Comment: Hey friend, Have i shared any different ans than this?

Comment: Doesn't matter, since you both misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Twinkles, think you are correct! . User has also missed a trick in asking a que.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM Tablename WHERE (DAYS = 30 AND RATE = 2) OR (DAYS = 60 AND RATE = 0)
```